# natbib citep[]{} error if used in theorem options

Tags: natbib, amsthm

I am using natbib and amsthm. If I use `\citep[Thm. 4.5]{key}` in the options of my theorem environment I get the error:

**Argument of \NAT@@citetp has an extra }. \begin{thm}[\citep[Thm]**

Why can't I put a citep with options into the options of a theorem environment? Below I have my code sample.

Thank you, for your help

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\renewcommand\sf{\sffamily} 
\usepackage{scrhack}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}

\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, dsfont}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsopn}
\usepackage{bbold}
\usepackage{bbm}

\newtheoremstyle{mystyle}%                % Name
  {}%                                     % Space above
  {}%                                     % Space below
  {\normalfont}%                          % Body font
  {}%                                     % Indent amount
  {\bfseries}%                            % Theorem head font
  {}%                                    % Punctuation after theorem head
  { }%                                    % Space after theorem head, ' ', or \newline
  {}%                                     % Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning `normal')

\theoremstyle{mystyle}
\newtheorem{Theorem}{Theorem}%

\begin{document}


\begin{Theorem}[\citep[Thm]{cs_Foucart13}]
test
\end{Theorem}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat-d}
\bibliography{literatur}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
 \begin{Theorem}[\citep[Thm]{cs_Foucart13}]
```

means the option to `Theorem` is

```
\citep[Thm
```

and things go wrong from there.

Use

```
\begin{Theorem}[{\citep[Thm]{cs_Foucart13}}]
```

This applies to any LaTeX2e optional argument, not just theorems.