# Citation inside comments of Theorem leads to `! Argument of \@citex has an extra }.`

Tags: errors, citing, theorems

I am trying to obtain an output such as

> **Theorem 4** (see [1, Theorem 12]). *Statement of the theorem*.

Separately, the commands `\begin{Theorem}[comments]...` and `\cite[comments]{refname}` work fine, assuming the `comments` of the Theorem contain nothing crazy, and assuming that `\cite` is outside the comment environment of the Theorem. But together, such as in the following minimal code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}
\newtheorem{Theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\begin{Theorem}[see \cite[Theorem 12]{refname1}]
\end{Theorem}

\bibliographystyle{plain} \bibliography{b}
\end{document}
```

I get the error

> `! Argument of \@citex has an extra }.`

Note that it happens already *before Bibtex is run*, that is when the compiler hasn't read what `refname1` refers to. And running Bibtex doesn't change anything.

Any idea where this could come from or how to fix it?

Comment: @BambOo Thanks. I also found [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251906/natbib-citep-error-if-used-in-theorem-options) since then.